# Visual studio 6.0 compability on windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I wanna install Visual Studio 6.0 on my Windows 10 computer but I have some problems. If you can help me, I will be great. Firstly, I click to Setup file to install, and than I saw this screen below [image]

I click "No". After that, I saw This screen below
[image]

And I click "Tamam (its mean "OK")" and than I saw this screen [image]

And, after I wait 45 min, screen is shown like this in below [image]

How can I install it on my Windows 10 computer ?
Computer is waiting like be locked as shown as like last picture

Comment: VS 6.0 is millenia old. Any reason not to use VS 2017?

Comment: I suggest you install an older version of Windows in a virtual machine, and use that for VS6. And with the goal of migrating the code to a more modern environment (which could as simple as just loading the project into a later version of VS).

Comment: Install a VM witch Windows 95 and then install VS 6.0 there,

Comment: Did you run setup as administrator? You may also want to enable some compatibility settings.

Comment: @manni66 "a VM **witch**" - that's nice. It seems that I'm not the only one who mis-trusts these new fancy VM thingies...

Answer (score 1):

Install it on a Windows XP Virtual Machine. I think this is the last officially supported OS.

**UPDATE**
I could not find anything explicitly stating this, only this [Visual Studio 6.0: Installation and Setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243969(v=vs.60).aspx) and this [Microsoft Visual studio 6.0 on Microsoft Product Lifecycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/3042)

I think VS 6.0 was released in 1998 - [Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#6.0_.281998.29). I remember using it til 2004 when we upgraded to Visual Studio 2005. Which we now still have in some good old Windows XP MVs.

Comment: Due to the activation needed for Windows XP I would personally rather recommend Windows 2000.